# Graphical login without a keyboard

Tags: login

Is there an XDM variant (kdm, gdm etc.) that allows graphical login without a physical keyboard?

I have a tablet computer (like iPad, but Intel i5) running KDE and would prefer that users have to login to use it.  However, the virtual keyboard is not available in the xdm screens I have seen.

I could plug in keyboard, but that is kludgy; I'd prefer to do something more like Android's gesture login.

Do you know of any options?

Comment: Here's one more interested in pam_gesture!

Answer (score 2):

I know that GDM in recent versions of Fedora runs a panel with accessibility options available so that an on-screen keyboard can be run. I'm not sure how it's configured to do so though.

Comment: Any recent version of GDM has a virtual keyboard already configured. Search for a 'vitruvian man' icon at login screen.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just start the virtual keyboard by putting an appropriate line in `/etc/X11/xdm/Xsetup_0`?
(I think that's the file, I find the X login mechanism to be very confusing.)

For a gesture login or things like that, you probably need to look at PAM (Pluggable Authentication Modules), but I'm not sure if you can have a module that requires X.

Related, but not helping since they don't know either: [iPhone type login screen?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18585/iphone-type-login-screen)

Answer (score 0):

If you are gdm user you can add some kind of onscreen keaboard or gesture grapper to `/etc/gdm/Init/Default` just before `exit 0` This [mini howto for screen keaboard](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=7959338&postcount=8) will give you examples how to do it with `kdm` and with different virtual keyboards. Here's an example with `onboard`.

```
onboard -s 684x200 -x 170 -y 568 &
exit 0
```

I've also just updated an answer to [Iphone type login screen question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29767/14267) that will give you a quick'n'dirty way of getting login gestures. I do not advice it to be *the* solution because of security concerns.